# Credentials in Azure Functions, pass one credential around or call as needed?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have intermittent credential issues in my durable function app.

```sh
ManagedIdentityCredential will use App Service managed identity

EnvironmentCredential.get_token failed: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.

DefaultAzureCredential - EnvironmentCredential is unavailable
```

In each activity I call `DefaultAzureCredential`

```py
# some activity function
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

def my_func()...
```

Would it be better to create a credential in my orchestrator, *once*, and pass it around to my activities? I am also using system assigned identity, so should I use `ManagedIdentityCredential` instead to avoid the constant checks `DefaultAzureCredential` does?

```py
from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential
import azure.durable_functions as df


def orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
    
    # Create the credentials
    credentials = ManagedIdentityCredential()

    # Pass it to my activity instead of my activity creating its own
    activity = yield context.call_activity("my_activity", credentials)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would it be better to create a credential in my orchestrator, once, and pass it around to my activities?

According to my understanding, if your `Orchestrator function` calls the `Activity function` multiple times, it is better to pass the `Credential` in the `Orchestrator function`; if it is only called once, I think it is the same to create a `Credential` in the `Activity function`.

> I am also using system assigned identity, so should I use ManagedIdentityCredential instead to avoid the constant checks DefaultAzureCredential does?

If you use `System assigned identity`, you can directly use `ManagedIdentityCredential`, because `DefaultAzureCredential` will check multiple identities until one of them provides a token.

For a better understanding, you can refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-python).

[image]

`EnvironmentCredential is unavailable` is caused by `DefaultAzureRedential` failing to request tokens from `EnvironmentCredential`, which is the expected result.